# Strategy game — one faction is 'Trailer Trash'

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I saw an advertisement for this a long time ago — probably around the mid-late '90s.

It showed the picture of a worn-down trailer with a stereotypical "white trash" man sitting on a lawn chair nearby and mentioned four playable 'tribes' — two of the tribes mentioned were "Trailer Trash" and "Amazons." Unfortunately I don't recall what the other two tribes were supposed to be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is [Tribal Rage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_Rage), a real time strategy game released in 1998.

> The game features six playable tribes:
>
> Bikers, Cyborgs, Enforcers, Amazons, Death Cultists, Trailer Trash

It's possible this is the picture you remember:

[image]

Comment: Ah, Tribal Rage. Also a good album by Jennifer Batten